what's the standard way of keras.model.predict to predict a single sample
I have a trained model,and load it in the follow way. Since I have custom loss.
Nx=512
Ny=512
Ntot=Nx*Ny
totsize=500
batchsize =5

def dice_coef_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_f = tf.reshape(y_true,[-1])
    y_pred_f = tf.reshape(y_pred,[-1])
    return tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(y_true_f-y_pred_f))/(Ntot*batchsize)

model=tf.keras.models.load_model('path_to_saved_model.keras',custom_objects={'dice_coef_loss':dice_coef_loss})

And in the training process, my dataset is in the follow way.
def decode(x,y):
    image = tf.io.read_file(x)
    image = tf.io.decode_raw(image, out_type=tf.float32)
    image = tf.transpose(tf.reshape(image,[Ny,Nx]),[1,0])
    image = tf.expand_dims(image,2)

    label = tf.io.read_file(y)
    label = tf.io.decode_raw(label, out_type=tf.float32)
    label = tf.transpose(tf.reshape(label,(Ny,Nx)),[1,0])
    label = label/np.pi
    label = tf.expand_dims(label,2)

    return image,label

dataset= tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((files_in_train,files_in_label))
dataset=dataset.map(decode,num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
dataset=dataset.batch(batchsize)

when I want to test the time of predict using the trained model, I first use
start=time.perf_counter()
ypre=model.predict(dataset.take(1))
end=time.perf_counter()
print('predict time: %s Seconds'%(end-start))

ypre.shape is (5, 512, 512, 1) and
predict time: 2.670394100015983 Seconds
so in princeple every sample cost time 2.6/5 ? but when I define another dataset2 with batch 1.
def decode2(x):
    image = tf.io.read_file(x)
    image = tf.io.decode_raw(image, out_type=tf.float32)
    image = tf.transpose(tf.reshape(image,[Ny,Nx]),[1,0])
    image = tf.expand_dims(image,2)

    return image

dataset2= tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((files_in_train))
dataset2=dataset2.map(decode2,num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
dataset2=dataset2.batch(1)

and test the predict time similarly.
start=time.perf_counter()
ypre=model.predict(dataset2.take(1))
end=time.perf_counter()
print('predict time: %s Seconds'%(end-start))

I get
predict time: 34.888951200060546 Seconds
I don't know why the time for predicting one sample is much slower than five sample. And I test other batchsize of the dataset2, it's seem that only  when batchsize is same as the batchsize of training ,  the time is correct.
So what's the correct way when I want to predict only one sample?
